# Reset individual share settings for files in shared folder

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-shared-folder

I want to remove individual sharing settings for thousands files and subfolders inside shared folder. Such way that **top folder only** shared setting can influence on sharing settings of files.

### How to reproduce

1. Create folder `Parent folder`. Set share settings to `User1`
2. Create `file1`, `file2` inside. At this point files are shared with `User1`
3. For `file2` add share for `User2`
4. Now if we set `Parent folder` share to `user3` only, `file2` remains shared with `user2`.

How to remove, or better to say **reset** this **individual** sharing setting for files deep inside child-folders?

Comment: I would like all files in `Parent folder` begin to shared only with `user3`. I know it's not default behavior by design. But is there **any** possibility to do this?

Comment: Looks like it makes sense. I will try on my files. The speed of spreading settings on many files in Drive is not fast. So it's better to wait before say what was happen exactly.

Comment: Nope -( It's not working. I have tryed on experimantal folder.